# how to get users from SharePoint user profile db using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to know, is there any way to get a SharePoint user using javascript / jquery from default SharePoint 2010 user profile db?

My requirement is to form an array of all SharePoint site users (user name) and use this array in a java function (that run behind the page at client side ) as a data source for a SPServices function.

Please provide any fisible solution or any other approach for building the array for javascript.

Comment: You say 'get a sharepoint user' and also 'an array of all sharepoint site users'. The answer depends based on which you want to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out http://SPServices.codeplex.com, it has functions to interact with the user profile service, specifically the UserProfileService operations.

Comment: Eric's right: SPService rocks. (I wrote it.)

Comment: we used this awesome library for our dynamic phonebook. It rocks!

Comment: Ditto. It is an awesome plugin.